# Is there any launcher app that behave like Iphone?

Tags: launcher, ios, launcherpro

I've just switched from Iphone to Android (CM7), and I strongly prefer the Iphone way to manage apps. The separation between Home screen and App Drawer screen on Android is very awkward. Is there any launcher app that behave like Iphone, ie. manage, arrange apps right on the home screen?

Apps I've used: LauncherPro, GO Launcher Ex, and ADWLauncher

Comment: I've never used CM, but **all** the ROMs and launchers I've used allow apps right on the home screen.

Comment: Almost every launcher allows adding apps from Drawer to the home screen. What  I want is _not_ having to add apps to home screen: installed apps appear right on home screen like on iPhone and can be managed from there.

Comment: Ah, got it.  I'm sure there's an app that will copy them all with one click, but I understand why not needing to deal with that at all would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've already rooted and flashed your ROM, you can give the MIUI rom a go, see http://en.miui.com/

I feel that is sort of the iPhone feel ROM for Android... no app drawer, newly installed apps get put onto the next available space on your screens. Folders to organise etc. Even the settings look iPhone-ish.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try later. I don't need the iPhone look, I just want the home screen to _behave_ like iPhone, it's much easier and simpler concept to understand than the app drawer thing.

Comment: @Lamnk He says there's no app drawer and the installed apps get on the homescreen itself.. isnt this the answer you are looking for?

Comment: From what he describes then yes it is. However I must try it first hand to find out.

Answer (score 1):

[Espier Launcher](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.espier.launcher&hl=en) is very much like iOS.  It has similar icon types, and it doesn't separate the Home Screen from the App Drawer.  It's also discussed [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17531/3415) (and is, in fact, how I heard about it).

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Could you please update the link?