# Launcher without home screen?

Tags: home-screen, launcher

Is there a launcher software for my Android device (in this case Galaxy S2) that doesn't have a home screen, but only the App drawer?

If I can give example it would be an iOS; you unlock and you are instantly on applications. The reason for this is I don't really use widgets at all, and I don't see the point in having a home screen only for apps shortcuts if I would have only menu (app draw).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Espier Launcher](https://www.appbrain.com/app/mobi.espier.launcher) might be the closest thing you can get to an "iOS experience".

I gave it a test run, it does not have an app drawer...  It's pretty much exactly like iOS.

Note: Espier Launcher is no longer available in Play Store since 2013.

Answer (score 1):

My just-released [TinyLaunch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.omegacentauri.TinyLaunch) is a tiny PalmOS-style launcher that just shows a (categorizable) list of apps.