# Any Android keyboards that operate & feel like you're using an iPhone iOS keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, ios

I've been using iOS since iPhone 1 and now am on iPhone 5.

Hence, at times I find bunch of Android things confusing and unfamiliar.

So, in addition to launcher's that work well for iPhone users, I'd like to find suitable way to make the keyboard comfy/ match an iPhone user.

[Is there any launcher app that behave like Iphone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11244/is-there-any-launcher-app-that-behave-like-iphone?rq=1)

One of the primary interactions one has with the phone is its keyboard which comes into play with every app i.e. messaging, notes and so on.

Few times I considered moving to Android and just felt out of place using Android keyboard.

I do not like the Swype keyboards etc as well.

Given that Android supports variety of custom keyboards, I was hoping that someone replicated the exact "typing feel, interaction & look" of iPhone iOS keyboard on Android for people who are coming in from the other side.

I do not really care for the "look" but would like to have "it feel" as if I am wearing the iPhone "glove" that fits well.

**I'm not just looking for color and shape, but "behavior" & "responsiveness" and full emulation/ copying of iPhone keyboard behaviors E.g. How the iphone letters of "pop up above the key" around when pressed.**

I'm sure there are other intricate behaviors that someone with a fine eye or UI/UX insight would be able to observe and then maybe replicate/ hack towards Android.

Comment: Are you asking us to find/recommend such a keyboard?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman - 1. Is it possible? 2. Does it exist?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575). Also see my app-list on [Keyboards & Input Methods](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_keyboards) ;)

Comment: How about we take this not as a software but a hack or mod to make it more like iPhone. I've been reading Qs on this SE that ask about ROM or Launcher that is more iPhone like.

Comment: Can you describe what do you mean by "typing feel, interaction & look" of the iPhone keyboard?  I personally don't like this keyboard.

Comment: @Alex.S You dont like "which keyboard?" What is there to describe, it has a certain usage & feel and that's what I'd like.

Comment: What you are trying to do is perfectly reasonable, but wouldn't it be beneficial to just try the Android keyboard for a while? I had an iPhone for a number of years before switching to an Android, and I'll never go back. And the keyboard didn't bother me. In fact, I much prefer it.

Comment: @DogLover I do not intend to go Android cold turkey. Maybe keep a 2nd android phone around and use it with my iPhone - Hence, I will need it to comply with iPhone usage feel, which I love & which works for me.

Comment: @AlexS Out of curiosity, if you're so fond of your iPhone, why are you changing to Android?

Comment: @DogLover Who said I'm changing over. I need a second phone & android to serve some utility & purpose. Ps: problem with most people is they hold their biases so strongly that it's like changing a religion to most. Not to me. Everything has a strengths & weaknesses, pros & cons, and a fit & purpose, in this universe.

Comment: Hello all. Just a quick reminder that comments aren't for extended discussions, and this site isn't a venue to try to convince people they are making bad life choices. If you have an answer, post it; if you don't, there are plenty more questions to try.

Comment: @DanHulme - Thank you for bringing focus back to the topic & Q at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I haven't tried this one, but I found it by doing a quick Google search. The screenshots look decent and it appears as though it will do the job.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sixgreen.android.softkeyboard

If you're after the newer style, this one also seems alright:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arvin.applekeyboard

Comment: I'm not just looking for color and shape, but "behavior" & "responsiveness" and full emulation/ copying of iPhone keyboard behaviors E.g. How the iphone letters of "pop up above the key" around when pressed.

Comment: @AlexS I very much doubt such a keyboard exists. And if it did, it would undoubtedly result in legal action from Apple.

Comment: the beauty of android is that it's open, so hoping that someone/ 3rd party creates it but is too small or unknown for Apple to sue